# Better way of editing certain fields in a json object?

Tags: javascript, json, redux

I have a javascript state object like this:

```
expFormErrors: { 
    position: false, 
    company: false, 
    dateStart: false, 
    dateEnd: false
}
```

I have an input field that is supposed to validate.
My validation function goes as follows. Very simple.

```
function validateText(text, fieldError, fieldInStringFormat) {
    let minLength = 3;
    let maxLength = 30;
    let hasError = false;
    if(text.length < minLength || text.length > maxLength) {
        hasError = true;
    } else hasError = false;
    return {
        type: VALIDATE_TEXT,
        payload: { field: fieldInStringFormat, fieldError: hasError }
}
```

Ok, so it basically dispatches a redux store update. Inside the reducer I have a switch statement that updates the state according to what is put into the `fieldInStringFormat` parameter. Doing it this way seems to me, a huge amount of code to accomplish something simple... here is how it would look in the reducer.

```
switch(action.fieldInStringFormat){
case 'position':
    return {
        ...state,
        expFormError: action.payload.fieldError,
        expFormErrors: { 
            ...state.expFormErrors, 
            position: action.payload.fieldError }
        };
case 'company': 
    return {
        ...state,
        expFormError: action.payload.fieldError,
        expFormErrors: { 
            ...state.expFormErrors, 
            company: action.payload.fieldError 
        }
};
}
```

As you can see this is a whole lot of repeating code, which I believe is something nobody wants. 'Never repeat yourself' Say I had an object with 100 fields, typing all of that would be ridiculous.

Is there a better way of doing this? I tried looking up various JSON references but couldn't find any built in way of doing this.

What I imagined as a solution would be something like this:

```
return {
    ...state,
    expFormErrors: { 
        ...state.expFormErrors,
        [someParameterStringWhichWouldEqualTheWantedField]: action.payload.fieldError
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the term you want is [computed property keys](http://www.benmvp.com/learning-es6-enhanced-object-literals/).  They will do exactly what you need:

```
return {
  ...state,
  expFormErrors: {
    ...state.expFormErrors,
    [action.fieldInStringFormat]: action.payload.fieldError
  }
};
```

Comment: WOW, I was close and had the right idea but wasn't too sure... thanks man! The link you provided is pure gold thanks!